# How to use ejs template to run a for loop on the integer array received from angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, for-loop, ejs

Was trying my hands at angularjs with ejs to run a for loop on an integer array received on the ejs template from an angularjs controller.

Following is the code for that:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
    <div><label>Trying to run the for loop on {{myCtrl.getMyIntegerArray()}} array</label></div>
    <select class="form-control  input-xsmall inline">
        <option>Year</option>
        <% for(var i=0; i <= {{myCtrl.getMyIntegerArray().length}}; i++) { %>
        <option>{{myCtrl.getMyIntegerArray()[i]}}</option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
</div>
```

Could somebody help me with it?

Comment: Why not just use the `ng-repeat` or `ng-options`?

Comment: @runTarm: could you help me with the code for `ng-reapt`? I tried it for a bit but couldn't work it out. Am new to angularjs and ejs.

Comment: @runTarm: `myIntegerArray = [1234, 5678, 9012, 3456];` is like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `ejs` here, angularjs has its own template engine.

You can achieve what you want by using `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<select class="form-control input-xsmall inline">
  <option>Year</option>
  <option ng-repeat="value in myCtrl.getMyIntegerArray()">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

But it's better to store the result in a `$scope` like this in the controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.getMyIntegerArray = function () {
    return [1234, 5678, 9012, 3456];
  };

  $scope.myIntegerArray = this.getMyIntegerArray();
});
```

and in html:

```
<select class="form-control input-xsmall inline">
  <option>Year</option>
  <option ng-repeat="value in myIntegerArray">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/IttzGJfOzYdP9Du0uAPh?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, it works like a charm now. Super stuff. Thanks :)